# How do I set up a Google Cloud Function (Python) to create a Google Cloud Project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have been using the GCP Python client library to automate project creation. I want to go serverless and use Cloud Functions and Pub/Sub. I can't figure out how to set up the dependencies and authentication. Anybody know?

I ran my python scripts from the cloud shell and everything worked. I tried running a pip freeze to capture the requirements, but that didn't work.

from main.py

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "./credentials.json"
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()


def call_function(event, context):
    service_proj_body = {
        "name": "gcp-functiontest30",
        "projectId": "gcp-functiontest30",
        "parent": {
            "id": '750256061723',
            "type": "organization"
        }
    }
    """Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Pub/Sub.
    Args:
         event (dict):  The dictionary with data specific to this type of
         event. The `data` field contains the PubsubMessage message. The
         `attributes` field will contain custom attributes if there are any.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): The Cloud Functions event
         metadata. The `event_id` field contains the Pub/Sub message ID. The
         `timestamp` field contains the publish time.
    """
    print("""This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {}
    """.format(context.event_id, context.timestamp))

    if 'data' in event:
        service = discovery.build(
            'cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
        request = service.projects().create(body=service_proj_body)
        response = request.execute()
        print(response)
    else:
        print('Sorry.')
```

I get a ton of errors for my deployed cloud function [error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5IhX.jpg)

Requirements.txt

```
google-api-core==1.14.2
google-api-python-client==1.7.11
google-auth==1.6.3
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.0
google-cloud-core==1.0.3
google-cloud-logging==1.12.1
google-cloud-resource-manager
google-pasta==0.1.7
google-resumable-media==0.3.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
Flask==0.10.1
httplib2==0.13.1
Markdown==2.5.2
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.1.0

pathlib2==2.3.4

requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0


uritemplate
WebTest
pycrypto
pyopenssl
```

Comment: Can you share your errors and your requirements.txt ? Do you deploy on the GUI or with the CLI ? If the CLI, share your commande line. Thanks

Comment: @guillaume - I am attempting to deploy through the GUI for now. I can download the error logs as well, if needed.

Comment: You should have conflict in your dependencies. Try to delete this line `import googleapiclient.discovery`. But it's complicated to diagnose with you huge requirements.txt. Do you really need to down all the internet? If you want to set up project and services, why you don't use Terraform or Deployment Manager?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have pared down the code I am using. The requirements were the result of the Cloud Shell environment, as I didn't know which I needed. I have been specifically tasked with python client automation, so terraform won't work. Also, I'm not deploying an application, per say, or instances. I'm just creating a GCP project and enabling it's necessary services.

Comment: I recommend you to start a virtual env and to create the minimal requirements.txt file for a working code in this venv. It will be easier then.

Comment: I second Guillaume's comment. You have collisions based upon incompatible libraries. Use `pylint` and remove the import statements for any libraries you don't need (the import statements and not an uninstall). Then use `virtualenv` to isolate your setup and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you how I figure out the authentication progress on Cloud Functions.

```
# for Cloud Functions use 

def get_service():
    import googleapiclient.discovery
    return googleapiclient.discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1',  cache_discovery=False)

service = get_service()
```

Requirements.txt

```
google-api-python-client
oauth2client
```